# Google mock for qabstractsocket class

Tags: qt, googlemock, qt-signals, qtcpsocket, qt-slot

I'm trying to solve my unit testing problem. I have a class with a `QTcpSocket` object in it. This class has derived from the `QObject` to use the signal/slot system and the socket object is used inside slots. 
I have tried to mock (gmock) this socket object, but I couldn't find any solution to incorporate the mock object to my class.

I cannot do this through a template, because the MOC compiler doesn't work with templates. And I cannot create a general interface for the QTcpSocket and my mock class. Though the QAbstractSocket has virtual methods, it has non-virtual methods like `waitForReadyRead()` too. That confuse me.

Comment: What means "mock this socket object" and "incorporate the mock object to my class"?

Comment: "mock this socket object" - create a class that emulates the QTcpSocket behaviour (for example with a name like a TcpSocketMock) , "incorporate the mock object to my class" - inject a TcpSocketMock object to the class that I want to test (that class is a 'driver' for a device that is connected by a tcp connection)

Comment: @ОлегЮрченко, Have you found a solution to this type of problem?